# Challenging Problem of Linear Permutation by H.C. Rajpoot

Tags: probability

How many numbers are lying between 20045757087 & 87050752074 when all the 11-digit significant numbers, formed by permuting the digits 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8 together, are arranged in decreasing order?

Note: All the numbers (linear permutations) have 11 digits & the replacement of the digits is not permitted.

Comment: Here is the detailed discussion on analytic formula for finding the correct ranks of words and numbers and other linear permutations (without replacement): https://www.academia.edu/10436842/HCRs_Rank_Formula_1_to_calculate_rank_of_any_linear_permutation_all_the_articles_are_permuted_together_without_any_replacement_

Answer (score 2):

Given $a \in \mathbb N^{d}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^d a_i =s$, there are ${s \choose a} = \frac{s!}{a_1! \ldots a_{d}!}$ strings of $s$ letters from an alphabet of size $d$ with $a_j$ of the $j$'th letter.  Let the number of these
that are less than or equal to a given $x \in \{1,\ldots, d\}^s$ in lexicographic order be $N_s(x)$.  We take $N_0(x) = 1$ where $x$ is the empty string.
Let $A(x)$ be the number of occurrences of each letter $j$ in $x$, let $x'$ be $x$ with the first letter removed, and let $e_i$ be the vector with $1$ in position $i$ and $0$ everywhere else.
$$ N_s(x) = \sum_{i < x_1, A(x)_i > 0} {s-1 \choose A(x) - e_i} + N_{s-1}(x') $$

If by "between" you are excluding the endpoints, the number you want is
$N_{11}(87050752074) - N_{11}(20045757087) - 1$.  I get $390382$.

Comment: Dear Professor Robert Israel, I am waiting to your comments in my question. Thank you for your kind help. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220706/constructing-a-quasiconvex-function